# ASP.NET App Exports to Excel (or not in this case)

Tags: asp.net, windows, iis-7, com, ms-office

Exising .net 2 app migrated to .net 4 and moved to an IIS7 Windows 2008 R2 server.

We used to be able to run some code on the web page to export some stuff to excel.

Now, when we do... we get the following error:

> The machine-default permission settings do not grant Local Activation permission for the COM Server application with CLSID  {00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} and APPID
>   Unavailable to the user d"omain\username" SID (S-1-5-21-2084383492-816144152-925700815-4150) from address LocalHost (Using LRPC). This security permission can be modified using the Component Services administrative tool.

Any thoughts?

I did wonder if it may be to do with the authenticated user being on a different domain to the webserver - where we see this error??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restarted the web server and this error no longer appears... I get another error when I try and do the workbook save... I'll post another question on that.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Try following this resolution:

[Microsoft Support](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/899965)

I believe that the basics of the error are the same.  The user you are trying to run the DCOm component as does not have permission to start it.